# ROS networking unable to see mesages published by slave computer

Tags: wifi, ros-kinetic, network, rosmaster, beagleboneblack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic on both a Beaglebone black(Master) and intel NUC(Slave). My problem is connecting the NUC to the ros master on the beaglebone over wifi. I set the ip address of the BBB as 10.0.0.30 and IP address of the NUC as 10.0.0.35. I am able to launch a publishing node on the BBB and echo those /turtle1/cmd_vel messages on the slave but not the other way around. Below are the shell scripts that run on boot on both machines and output of roswtf on each machine when the publisher is running on the nuc(slave) and I am attempting to see the data on the BBB.

BBB(master):

```
 #! /bin/bash
cd $(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
. devel/setup.bash
ulimit -c unlimited
export ROS_IP=10.0.0.30
until ping -c1 $ROS_IP &>/dev/null; do :; done
roslaunch robot2017 main.launch
#roslaunch robot2017 turtle_pub.launch
```

roswtf on BBB(Master)

```
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
unknown network error contacting node: timed out
unknown network error contacting node: timed out
unknown network error contacting node: timed out
unknown network error contacting node: timed out
unknown network error contacting node: timed out
unknown network error contacting node: timed out
unknown network error contacting node: timed out
^C... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /drive_node:
   * /robot/autonomy


Found 2 error(s).

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /test_publish->/rosout (/rosout)

ERROR Errors connecting to the following services:
 * service [/test_publish/set_logger_level] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/test_publish/set_logger_level], address [rosrpc://10.0.0.35:47211]
 * service [/test_publish/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/test_publish/get_loggers], address [rosrpc://10.0.0.35:47211]
```

NUC (slave)

```
#! /bin/sh
. /home/astrobotics/ros_code/devel/setup.sh
#export ROS_IP=localhost
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.0.0.30:11311
export ROS_IP=10.0.0.35
#roslaunch autonomous_control autonomous.launch
roslaunch autonomous_control turtle_test.launch
#roslaunch turtlesim turtlesim_node
```

roswtf on NUC(slave)

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
roswtf lost connection to the ROS Master at http://10.0.0.30:11311

Aborting checks, partial results summary:

Found 2 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING Communication with node [/ds2017] is very slow
WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /drive_node:
   * /robot/autonomy


Found 2 error(s).

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /test_publish->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /test_publish->/rostopic_1664_1495679183324 (/turtle1/cmd_vel)

ERROR cannot contact ROS Master at http://10.0.0.30:11311
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281931/ros-networking-unable-to-see-mesages-published-by-slave-computer/) by [skynet](https://answers.ros.org/users/33478/skynet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2018-02-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [huanxiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28265/huanxiner/) on 2018-02-06**:
NUC seems to have the same startup script as master, is that a typo?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-06**:
Can you please clarify why this is not a duplicate of #q281760 and #q281434? If it is a duplicate: please close / delete this one, pick one of the others and update that.

Please don't post duplicates of your question unnecessarily.

#q281760 even has some comments already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out it was a firewall issue that turned on after an update.

---

Originally posted by [skynet](https://answers.ros.org/users/33478/skynet/) with karma: 20 on 2018-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0